# Google Sheet - sumif values with texts

Tags: google-sheets, sum, sumifs

## 1 Sum values

I want to sum all the values from A column, according to the date when they were added.

To do this I added another two columns - Date, containing the list of dates (kind a filter) and Sum. To the Sum I added function =SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, D2) where A is the range of values, B is the date the value was added and D - the filter.
The problem is it sum only those rows that have no text inside, only numbers.
I need to sum those with texts also, please feel free to check the demo:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D8Kak0QRKdWK1-c22xI3Q7nJwbWWuLhpRU7A5lUiiYQ/edit?usp=sharing

## 2 extend to the entire column

In this doc I am struggling with one more problem. Column A and B is filled automatically through Google Forms but D and E so the date and formula I need to extend throughout these columns. I tried the basic stretching option but it doesn't work well in this case. Is there a way to do this simply without copying it again and again?

Thank you!

Comment: I was going to suggest an array formula to populate the whole column but I'm not sure how with sumifs.  You can do a count of dates by using a pivot table.  Select the date column and then select the data menu and click on pivot.  Choose the date column for the rows and values.

Comment: @Gordon Maybe I do something wrong but it doesn't work here, thanks anyway!

Comment: I didn't see the text and number mix in column A.  I've changed the formula in column C to pick up numbers on their own and added the pivot table I mentioned.  have a look. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P2SvAQuaTDxC3Tv-UoTPap0PIuqR1p_Cqe7C3twPsoE/edit?usp=sharing